# Grails: how can I query domain class' hasMany-relationship against intersecting set of objects?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, intersection

I have about the following:

```
class Object_1 {
  static hasMany = [tags:Tag]
  Set tags;
  ...
}
```

Now I have a set of tags and want to find all Object_1-instances with intersecting (!= matching) tags. I was thinking of something like

```
Object_1.findAllByTagsInList(tags);
```

But that does not work at all - I get a "nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query". I have the feeling I am missing something important. Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an elegant way to solve the problem. I redesigned the relationship to be many-to-many which allows for simply iterating over the tags list finding all the relevant objects.

... of course now I have to take care of that relationship a couple of times - but I am happy to have this working with few locs.

Comment: Yep, `Tag.findAllByObject_1AndIdInList(o.tags.id)` could work.

Answer (score -1):

"in list" is not one of [the operators](http://www.grails.org/OperatorNamesInDynamicMethods) recognized in dynamic finder methods - that won't work.

Instead, you'll have to use [HQL or the criteria builder](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Querying) to formulate your query (and perhaps put it in a static finder method).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I really did not see that. And I think it is somewhat contradicting to http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html where "InList" is mentioned. Then again not for "find_All_By" as I also noticed right now. 

Would you have an example for such a criterion? I played around with those and thought I got close - but didn't really make it work.

Comment: Actually, it is. That documentation is outdated, see `AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod`. What doesn't work that way is querying collection properties: `tags` can't be `inList` because it's a `List` itself.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I had in mind to supply tags as the list of possible values it could be in.